# Rails not loading referencial attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, models, database-migration

I have a two models, User and Role. I added a migration that looks like:

```
class AddRoleReferenceToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_reference :users, :role, index: true
  end
end
```

Now my schema looks like this:

```
create_table "roles", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "role_id"
end
add_index "users", ["role_id"], name: "index_users_on_role_id", using: :btree
```

And my models like this:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :role
end
```

In my seed.rb I am trying to do:

```
user = User.create(email:"example@example.com" name:"Ben")
<Initialize Role table with some values>
user.role = Role.first
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where    clause': SELECT  `roles`.* FROM `roles`  WHERE `roles`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:301:in `query'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:301:in `block in execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:301:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:232:in `exec_query'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:240:in `select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:31:in `select_all'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:69:in `select_all'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:603:in `exec_queries'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/association_relation.rb:15:in `exec_queries'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:487:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:231:in `to_a'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:451:in `find_take'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:98:in `take'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:42:in `find_target'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:138:in `load_target'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:53:in `reload'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:9:in `reader'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:110:in `role'
/Users/ryancollins/RubymineProjects/StreamBoard/db/seeds.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:184:in `load_seed'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Why would it be looking for a foreign key for user in roles when I have clearly stated the relationship in my models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `belongs_to` in Rails, you're saying that the model containing the `belongs_to` has the foreign key to the other object.  In this case, you've placed the foreign key, `role_id` on the `User` model.  Therefore, the `User` model should contain the `belongs_to :role`, and the `Role` model should contain `has_many :users`.

Comment: Okay I see the mistake now even though it makes more sense to me lexicographically to have it the other way around. I am now getting: **NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass** after I changed the relationships

Comment: super_role = Role.find_by_name('Super Admin')

print super_role.name

user.role << super_role

user.organizations << default_organization

Comment: `user.role` is not an array.  It's for a single object.  Change `user.role << super_role` to `user.role = super_role`.  The way that you've constructed your model is that a user can only belong to one role.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much for all the help Sean and Carlos.

Comment: I thought this was working fine as I was no longer getting an error, but I have found that it does not actually set the role id. I have a warning when I do user.role = super_role **Unresolved Ruby Reference**

Comment: How are you running this script?  I've never seen that before, outside of RubyMine.  One thing to check for is that you've actually run the migration.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using has_one and belongs_to the other way around.

Your models should look like this:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Comment: If he uses `has_one :user` on the `Role` model, then he is going to create a one-to-one relationship between `Role` and `User`.  I'm going to guess that's not what he wants.  Typically, roles are built in a one-to-many or many-to-many fashion.